# mark point on graph matlab

Tags: matlab, point

i have this function that draw specific equation:

```
function [  ] = draw(  )

x=linspace(-2,2,400);
for i=1:400
y(i)=cos(x(i)^2)-5*x(i)*sin(x(i)/2);
end

plot(x,y)
title('2-D line plot for the equation')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')

end
```

now, I want to write another function that will use  `draw` and mark the root off the function. Assuming I know the x,y of the root i want to mark.

how can I do that? once i call   `draw` the graph is plotted without my roots.

Comment: Do you mean you want to mark it with text at the right location? If so you can use a text annotation directly inside your draw function. Oh and note that you can replace your for-loop with this vectorized form: y=cos(x.^2)-5.*x.*sin(x./2);

Comment: Check [this blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/02/08/string-annotations-for-plots/) post for some good examples for putting text markers in plots

Comment: Do you really need to call another function or you can just put the whole code in draw?

Comment: I guess i will put the whole code in draw, seems like its easier.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment you could add a few lines in your existing function to achieve what you want. Note that if you know beforehand the location of the roots it's easier and you can skip that part in the code. It's commented so it should be quite easy to follow. Please tell me if I'm off the track or there is something unclear:

```
clear
clc
close all

x=linspace(-2,2,400);

%// for i=1:400
%// y(i)=cos(x(i)^2)-5*x(i)*sin(x(i)/2);
%// end

%// Vectorized function
y= cos(x.^2)-5.*x.*sin(x./2);

%// If you already have the roots skip this part 

%// ================================================
%// Create function handles to find roots.
fun = @(x) cos(x^2)-5*x*sin(x/2);

x0_1 = -1; %// Initial guesses for finding roots
x0_2 = 1;
a1 = fzero(fun,x0_1);
a2 = fzero(fun,x0_2);

%// ================================================

%// At this point you have the x-values of both roots (a1 and a2) as well
%// as their y-values, corresponding to fun(a1) and fun(a2), respectively).

%// Plot the function
plot(x,y)

hold on

%// Use scatter to mark the actual points on the curve. Highly
%// customizable.
hS1 = scatter(a1,fun(a1),300,'+','MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7]);
hS2 = scatter(a2,fun(a2),300,'+','MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5],'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7]);

%// Generate text strings. There are other ways as well, like using
%num2string[...].
TextString1 = sprintf('Root 1 is at (%0.1f,%0.1f)', a1,fun(a1));
TextString2 = sprintf('Root 2 is at (%0.1f,%0.1f)', a2,fun(a2));


%// Place text with those 2 lines at the location you want.
text(a1-1,fun(a1)+1,TextString1)
text(a2+.25,fun(a2)+1,TextString2)

title('2-D line plot for the equation')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

Which outputs something like this:

[image]

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @saharz so did that answer help you solve your problem?